# How do I add a node to a pseudo-distributed hadoop setup?

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing

I've a [single-node pseudo-distributed hadoop setup](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/single_node_setup.html#PseudoDistributed) on a unix system in the network. What are the minimum steps to add another computer/node (cygwin) on the network to form a hadoop [cluster setup](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/cluster_setup.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instructions for Hadoop a single node cluster.

http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2007/08/05/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu/

Instructions for Hadoop a multi node cluster.

http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2007/08/09/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-part-2-multi-node-cluster/

The author Michael makes installation and configuration very easy and had been keeping the instructions up to date.